# Problema Android Build transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug colgado

Tags: android, build

Tengo un proyecto Android el cual al ejecutar el build lleva aproximadamente 10horas (y sumando) ejecutando la tarea:

`app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug`

me imagino esto no es normal, a que se puede deber? y que puedo hacer para corregirlo?

Por el momento he detectado que el problema viene asociado a una lib externa que necesito utilizar ya que al quitarla el build finaliza en no mas de 2 minutos.

La lib que estoy intentando utilizar es la `"org.apache.tika"`.

Este es mi build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gvideo.sgutierc.cl.videorecorder"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.14'
    api files('libs/lib.file.metadata.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso al compilar tu aplicación al parecer llego al limite de referencia de 64Kb,  agrega la propiedad `multiDexEnabled = true` dentro de

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
     ...
      multiDexEnabled true
     ...
    }
}
```

Revisa la documentación acerca de :

**[Configurar apps con métodos de más de 64K](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es-419)**

> **Acerca del límite de referencia de 64K** Los archivos de las apps de Android (APK) contienen archivos de códigos de byte ejecutables en
>   forma de archivos Dalvik Executable (DEX), que contienen el código
>   compilado empleado para ejecutar tu app. La especificación de Dalvik
>   Executable limita la cantidad total de métodos a los que se puede
>   hacer referencia en un archivo Dex a 65 536, incluidos los métodos del
>   framework de Android, de biblioteca y de tu propio código. En el
>   contexto de la informática, el término Kilo, K, denota 1024 (o 2^10).
>   Debido a que 65 536 es igual a 64 X 1024, este límite se denomina
>   “límite de referencia de 64K”

---

Actualización:

> Tengo un proyecto Android el cual al ejecutar el build lleva
>   aproximadamente 10horas (y sumando) ejecutando la tarea.

Para compilar un proyecto esto no debe tomar tanto tiempo si esta sucediendo esto, debe a las siguientes razones.

- No tienes conexión a internet. Esto para bajar las dependencias especificadas en tu `build.gradle`.
- Estas bajo un proxy, necesitas agregar las credenciales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En ocasiones el proxy server determina bloquear algunos url los cuales son necesarios para descargar datos, esto aún y que agregues tus credenciales, te sugiero revisar el Log de Android Studio para revisar cual url es elproblema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, añadí la línea indicada pero sigue tomando mas tiempo de lo esperable, ya lleva 30 minutos...

Comment: No debe tardar tanto, si esta tardando es que tal vez no tienes conexión a internet , agregaste esto dentro de defaultConfig ?  Revisa mi actualización @Androide203

Comment: Así quedo mi gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gvideo.sgutierc.cl.videorecorder"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: No debe tardar tanto, si esta tardando es que tal vez no tienes conexión a internet , agregaste esto dentro de defaultConfig ?  Revisa mi actualización @Androide203

Comment: Revise la conexion a internet y esta correcta... he dejado el build corriendo durante la noche, ya lleva 15Horas >.<...